# Marquee of Images in android

Tags: android, image, marquee

I m working on the showing of marquee of images in my project.

I had referred this example from [github](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo).

My Problem is, i m in need of showing the images only on the top of the screen not in the entire screen(like thumb images).

In that github example, they had used LinearLayout for showing the images which is scrolled automatically.

In my case the images are dynamic , i have to retrieve them from the database.

The total of number images size may vary.

My problem is when i have reached the last image, auto scroll stops , Also if i have only two images, it won't scroll.

So i m keen to know, is there any other way to achieve marquee of images in android.